# Testing Instance methods of a connected Container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, enzyme

Hello I have a connected dashboard container. It has a child which is a connected redux-form. I would like to test the dashboard containers instance methods. I know I can wrap the dashboard in Provider to pass the store to the child components. But Then I lose access to wrapper.instance().someInstanceMethod() (Because im mounting Provider as root and no longer the Dashboard. Has anyone dealt with this and come up with a solution?

According to the error message Im getting I can pass store in as a prop explicitly but this is not working. nor is passing it as the second argument to wrap as context. Maybe im missing something. Below is an example test that does not work but it gives off the general idea of what im trying to do.

```
it('Should Handle Refresh', () => {
  _spies.load.should.have.not.been.called;
  let wrapper = mount(<Dashboard {..._props} {...store}/>);
  wrapper.instance().handleRefreshData();
  _spies.load.should.have.been.called.twice;
});
```

Comment: Shallow render actually still allows me to call instance methods. which I did not know. So you can do that if you only want to render 1 level deep and not worry about dealing with connected child components (Like redux form).

Comment: Have you tried passing it like this: `<Dashboard store={store} />` ?

Comment: Yeh I have which I think is working lol but since the connected component is a child. i dont think the store gets passed down the line. Although Im not positive on the exact way that Redux works in that manner. For now Im just testing instance methods using shallow rendering which doesnt render children. So i can get away with just exporting the undecorated component and testing that but shallow rendering will not allow me to test lifecycle methods so im still trying to find a better solution.